# powershell computer information script

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I need to create a powershell script you can double-click on (64-bit computer) and it will output to a .txt file in the same location as the powershell script to generate information on:

- Computer name/model/serial no.
- C drive size/available disk space on the C drive
- Which version operating system the computer is running
- Who is currently logged onto the computer

So far (but it's not quite working) I've got:

```
$computerSystem = get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem
$computerOS = get-wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem
$computerHDD = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter drivetype=3

$txtObject = New-Object PSObject -property @{
    'PCName' = $computerSystem.Name
    'Model' = $computerSystem.Model
    'SerialNumber' = $computerBIOS.SerialNumber
    'HDDSize' = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.Size/1GB)
    'HDDFree' = "{0:P2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/$computerHDD.Size)
    'OS' = $computerOS.caption
    'SP' = $computerOS.ServicePackMajorVersion
    'User' = $computerSystem.UserName
    } 

$txtObject | Select PCName, Model, SerialNumber, HDDSize, HDDFree, OS, SP, User | Get-Process | Out-File 'system-info.txt' -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Answer (score 1):

`$PSScriptRoot` = current location where your script is launched, so if you specify it in the save path like `Out-File "$PSScriptRoot\system-info.txt"`, it will be saved at the same location as the script

`Get-Process` can't be used at this position

`NoTypeInformation` does not exist as a parameter of `Out-File`

```
$computerSystem = get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem
$computerOS = get-wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem
$computerHDD = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter drivetype=3

$txtObject = New-Object PSObject -property @{
    'PCName' = $computerSystem.Name
    'Model' = $computerSystem.Model
    'SerialNumber' = $computerBIOS.SerialNumber
    'HDDSize' = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.Size/1GB)
    'HDDFree' = "{0:P2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/$computerHDD.Size)
    'OS' = $computerOS.caption
    'SP' = $computerOS.ServicePackMajorVersion
    'User' = $computerSystem.UserName
    } 

$txtObject | Select-Object PCName, Model, SerialNumber, HDDSize, HDDFree, OS, SP, User | Out-File "$PSScriptRoot\system-info.txt" -Append
```